# Programatically create nodes, taxonomies and relationships via exisiting database

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, database

I have a client that wants a Drupal port. They have a MySql DB with a small built by hand backend. The data structure is about standard in terms of a business organization.

People

- Department
- Specialty
- Location
- Etc

How can I create taxonomies as well as nodes from a MySql Script from the old database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://timonweb.com/how-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-drupal-7 - only thing to note is making sure the taxonomy terms don't exist before you add them, which you can easily do with a function like this (recently wrote this for a project)

```
function taxonomy_import_add_or_get_term($term, $vocabulary) {
  $tid = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term, $vocabulary->title);
  if (count($tid) > 0) {
    $tid = array_shift(array_keys($tid));
  }
  else {
    $term_object = new stdClass();
    $term_object->name = ucwords(strtolower($term));
    $term_object->vid = $vocabulary->vid;
    taxonomy_term_save($term_object);
    $tid = $term_object->tid;
  }
  return $tid;
}
```

Comment: Hell YEAH! Great Answer!

Comment: Only thing thou, when you mention about the terms not existing. I wanted to create terms from one of the tables in the db. Should I NOT do that?

Comment: You can create them from whatever you like. All depends on your structure. I just wanted to give you the relevant tools to create the pieces of the puzzle. A great way to make sure you're correctly populating everything is simply to create test nodes with all the fields populated and then look at them in the Devel tab, you can learn the structure and exactly which values go where that way.